# date picker OK/CANCEL button text changed to some other language in nougat(Moto G4 plus)

Tags: android, android-layout, android-datepicker, android-7.0-nougat

OK/CANCEL button in date picker is changed to some other language when i am trying to set Locale(en) at run time.

Note: 
 i) It is happening only in Moto G4 plus (Android 7.0).
 ii) Changing to some other language like chinese(zh), spanish(es) at runtime works properly.

Also working properly if i am using 'en-US' but not 'en', Why?

[Screen shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6R3dE.png)

Comment: Check does your mobile support that language from setting menu?

Comment: @piyush, yes, my mobile supports english(india,US,UK..).

Answer (score 4):

Use SetButton() function as follow

```
dialog.setButton(DatePickerDialog.BUTTON_POSITIVE, R.strings.ok, dialog);
dialog.setButton(DatePickerDialog.BUTTON_NEGATIVE, R.strings.cancel, (OnClickListener)null);
```

This will use String passed by you as button text and will solve your problem even you are using multiple language for an APP

Comment: I tried this before and it is working. But i just need a default date picker,  no need to customize.                                                                                If this is a only solution then i have to change the entire project date picker segment, that will be in more than 50 places.

Comment: You can use this methods on default date picker dialog present in android.app

Comment: Is there any simple way instead of changing the text in every(more than 50) date picker.

Comment: i dont think there is any easy solution for it. always use singleton pattern for such problems by which you can make changes at one place and you will get same object at every place. but now you need to do it manually at every place.

Comment: I am also having the same issue with my Moto G4 please provide stable solution to the bug.

Comment: Helpful! This code fixed my issue but getting the language issue for Month name as well. Can you help me out with month name also

Comment: @StutiKasliwal did  fix month name issue ?

Answer (score 0):

```
Add below themes in your applications style file:

//App theme
 <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
      name="android:datePickerDialogTheme">@style/PickerDialogTheme</item>
        <item name="android:timePickerDialogTheme">@style/PickerDialogTheme</item>
    </style>


<style name="PickerDialogTheme" parent="android:Theme.Material.Light.Dialog">
        <item name="android:colorAccent">@color/blue</item>
        <item name="android:textAllCaps">true</item>
        <item name="android:positiveButtonText">@string/ok_text</item>
        <item name="android:negativeButtonText">@string/cancel_text</item>
    </style>
```